# What is the missing number in this sequence and what is the pattern?

Tags: number-sequence

0, 4, 10, 32, ???, 317.  Note that ??? represents a 3 digit number.  All numbers are base 10 so don't bother trying to use other bases.  Also, don't use any difference between successive terms because the answer I am looking for doesn't use those.  There is a very specific pattern I am looking for so can anyone spot it?  What is the missing 5th number and why?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96920/what-is-the-missing-number-and-pattern-in-this-sequence

Comment: The closed one said I can edit it so I did.

Comment: "Rewording" means that you have to edit the question which has been closed. It'll then be reviewed  and if the edit is found to be satisfactory for reopening, your question will be reopened.

Comment: Number sequences are posted on this site, so why allow some and not others?  Makes no sense.  Not being fair to all posters.  I feel like my question is being targeted.

Comment: The original question was reopened so this duplicate is not needed anymore.